# How to find an error in a threaded Ruby program?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

In a thread, I'm doing the following:

```
builder_thread = Thread.new do
    FileUtils.cp_r(folder,dest)
    io_object = IO.popen(command)
    Thread.current["output"] = ""
    Thread.current["pid"] = io_object.pid
    Thread.current["basedir"] = dest
    io_object.each { |out| Thread.current["output"] += out }
end
```

and this works OK, when I access the thread's output like `thread_var["output"]`. However, if I turn the code into this:

```
builder_thread = Thread.new do
    dest = File.join(root_dir,"mydir")
    FileUtils.cp_r(folder,dest)
    io_object = IO.popen(command)
    Thread.current["output"] = ""
    Thread.current["pid"] = io_object.pid
    Thread.current["basedir"] = dest
    io_object.each { |out| Thread.current["output"] += out }
end
```

when I try to access `thread_var["output"]` is nil, just like if the code below `io_object = IO.popen(command)` doesn't get executed. In the first case, I'm creating the `dest` folder before it gets to the thread. In the second, I'm creating it in the thread. How can I figure out what's wrong? I am a beginner at Ruby threading.

### Edit

The command that gets executed inside that thread may take a very long time to complete. Meanwhile, I'd like to be able to access the `thread_var["output"]` variable & see how the command is doing. If I join the thread right before I access the value, everything works OK. However, joining the thread may take a very long time, and I like to not do that. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that an exception is being raised. Exceptions in threads other than the main thread aren't printed to the console - they just cause the thread to stop running.

Comment: An exception doesn't get raised. I checked. If I join the thread, everything works as expected. However, I would like to not have to join the thread, because it could take a lot of time to finish joining. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Apparently my check wasn't that through. You were right. Thanks!

Comment: You can use `-d` (debug mode) or `Thread.abort_on_exception = true` to ensure exceptions in other threads raise immediately.